# images sequence to video and overlay at the same time using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to reduce computational complexity of my program in order to speed up processing speed. However, I am not sure is there any way to combine to processes of **images sequence to video** and **overlaying** in to one process?

Something that I've implemented is sequential in such a way, 1th) images sequence is converted to video 2th) next process that is overlying happens.

All works as expected **BUT** it takes too long to 1th and 2th operations to be completed. Therefore, I am looking for combining this 2 operations.

**1th operation**

```
"-y -f concat -safe 0 -i {0} -vsync vfr -vf \"fps={1},format=yuv420p\" {2}"
```

**1th Code**

```
string cmd = String.Format("-y -f concat -safe 0 -i {0} -vsync vfr -vf \"fps={1},format=yuv420p\" {2}"
                    , frameList, frame_rate, output_file);
```

**2th operation**

```
-y -i {0} -i {1} -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -filter_complex \"{2}{3}\" {4} {5} -c:a copy {6}
```

**2th Code**

```
string setpts = String.Format("[1:v]setpts=PTS-{0}/TB[a];", 0);
//{0}:{1} position
string overlay = String.Format("[0:v][a]overlay={0}:{1}:enable=gte(t\\,{2}):eof_action=pass,format=yuv420p[out]", Program.FrameWidth - (480+25), 25, overlay_delay);
string map = "-map \"[out]\" -map 0:a?";
string pix_fmt = "";
string cmd = String.Format("-y -i {0} -i {1} -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -filter_complex \"{2}{3}\" {4} {5} -c:a copy {6}"
    , output_file, video_path, setpts, overlay, map, pix_fmt, output_file.Replace(".mp4", "_overlay_cam.mp4"));
```

I am appreciated your help.

Comment: Share your actual commands, after all substitutions.

Comment: @Gyan I have inserted codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
string setpts = String.Format("[1:v]setpts=PTS-{0}/TB[a];", 0);
string fps = String.Format("[0:v]fps={0}[i];", frame_rate);
//{0}:{1} position
string overlay = String.Format("[i][a]overlay={0}:{1}:enable=gte(t\\,{2}):eof_action=pass,format=yuv420p[out]", Program.FrameWidth - (480+25), 25, overlay_delay);
string map = "-map \"[out]\" -map 0:a?";
string pix_fmt = "";


string cmd = String.Format("-y -f concat -safe 0 -i {0} -i {1} -filter_complex \"{2}{3}{4}\" {5} {6} -c:a copy -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 {7}"
    , frameList, video_path, fps, setpts, overlay, map, pix_fmt, output_file.Replace(".mp4", "_overlay_cam.mp4"));
```

The fps filter is carried out on images before they are used for overlay. overlay filter is adjusted to use the output of the fps filter. Rest all remains the same.

Comment: Thank you very much , 37% improvement in time complexity and combination of 2 operations to 1 operation. great solution.